# How to set fonts for different OS on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mac, windows, font, qgs

I have a project set up on windows fonts and I use several of them for different layers, but while most users use windows, some use mac

When mac users open up the project they get the font not available error. Is there any way of making the project pick other fonts if the system is a mac? As in where in a layer I'm using Dubai Medium, on mac it would load Avenir Medium, where I'm using Segoe, on mac it changes to Helvetica?

As a last resort would there be a way to disable the font error warnings at a project level? (so the mac users see that the project loaded fine instead of asking for assistance with errors)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but you could try taking advantage of the @qgis_os_name global variable, which you can see in `Project > Properties > Variables > Global`, and try something like this as a font expression:

`IF(@qgis_os_name = 'windows', 'Dubai Medium', 'Avenir Medium')`